# CLPlacemark has no member 'get'

Tags: ios, swift4

I am referring one func to get user's location and the code is below:

```
func updateLocation(_ userLocation: CLLocation) {
  if (userLocation.horizontalAccuracy > 0) {
    self.locationService.stopUpdatingLocation()
    return
  }

  self.latitude = NSNumber(value: userLocation.coordinate.latitude as Double)
  self.longitude = NSNumber(value: userLocation.coordinate.longitude as Double)

  if !self.geocoder.isGeocoding {
    self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) in
      if let error = error {
        logger.error("reverse geodcode fail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
      }
      if let placemarks = placemarks, placemarks.count > 0 {
        // TODO:
        let onePlacemark = placemarks.get(index: 0)
        self.address = "\(onePlacemark?.administrativeArea,onePlacemark?.subLocality,onePlacemark?.thoroughfare)"
        self.city = (onePlacemark?.administrativeArea!)!
        self.street = (onePlacemark?.thoroughfare!)!
      }
    })
  }
}
```

When building the project, it threw something "CLPlacemark has no member 'get'" at this line:

```
let onePlacemark = placemarks.get(index: 0)
```

I am writing the project with swift 4.0, and

```
import Foundation
import INTULocationManager
```

is done.

Comment: `placemarks.get(index: 0)` => `placemarks[0]`?

Comment: Wow, it works, but why it is like that? sorry I am newbie of ios and swift...

Comment: That's call subscribing. It's present in a lot of languages.

Comment: I built the reference code but it doesn't throw the error... when using 'get' in that project...